# Prove that $Z(S_n)$ is trivial for $n \geq 3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Hi I am trying to solve this question I don't know where to begin but I have an idea so we have

$$Z(G) = \{x \in G \space  |\space  xy = yx \space\forall y \in G\}$$

We must show that for all $\sigma$ $\in S_n$ such that $\sigma \neq (1)$
Then there exists y $\in S_n$ such that $\sigma * y$ $\neq$ $y * \sigma$.
However I don't know how to proceed further.

I was thinking I could use conjugation somehow but I don't know what would I do with them.

Comment: Cheat : $Z(G)$ is normal in $G$ for any group $G$. Thus, via simplicity and nonabelianity of $A_n$, $Z(S_n)$ is forced to be trivial.

Comment: @BalarkaSen I don't understand the last part via simplicity and nonabelianity of $A_n$ , Z($S_n$) is forced to be trivial can you explain more please?

Comment: $Z(S_n)$ is normal in $S_n$, thus it must be either $A_n$ or trivial via simplicity of $A_n$. But $Z(S_n)$ cannot be $A_n$ since it's not abelian, hence $Z(S_n) = \{e\}$.

Comment: @BalarkaSen; $A_n$ is the only non-trivial subgroup of $S_n$ for $n\ge 5$ ;You need to consider the case for $ n=4$